# android studio change my password key after Generate Signed Bundle

Tags: android-studio, compiler-errors, signed, change-password, key-generator

I use Android Studio: Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Canary 12
I have a strange problem. I have key store, and I enter correct passords and alias and set "Remember passwords" as On. For the first time, everything is fine. But if I reuse Generate Signed Bundle, my key password has a different meaning and I have error:

```
> Task :app:packageRelease FAILED

Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
   > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key profit from store "D:\android_profit_key": Cannot recover key
```

And if I enter correct key password again - the error will disappear and the build will end.

Perhaps this is important:
My key was created on the Mac OS system. But now I use Windows 10.

Maybe now I must use Same passwords in key store and key password (Now they are different from each other.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed the following pattern:
When I decided to create a new key with different passwords I got two errors:
[image]

[image]

Thus, now the android studio does not start working correctly if the passwords are different.

**Decision:**
Create a new key or add an alias with the same password as the key itself.